# AsyncStorage.getItem() returns a single value AND a promise

Tags: javascript, react-native, asyncstorage

I'm trying to get a single value kept in my device by a AsyncStorage.setItem(KEY, VALUE);.

I have this **localStorage.js** file to manage local data

```
import React from 'react';
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';

const storageSet = async(key, value) => {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem(key, value);
    } catch(error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
}

const storageGet = async(key) => {
  try {
       const result = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key);
       console.log(result);
       return result;
    } catch(error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
}

export { storageSet, storageGet };
```

In **login.js** file I call these functions passing the parameters. It saves right.
But when I try to **getItem(**) values I have **two distinct returns**, a **promise** AND a **single value**. Follow:

console.log(result) **whithin** storageGet('key'), it's what I want.

```
57d7bc714b269533
1
ASUS_Z00AD
1.0
null
1
```

console.log(result) *out* storageGet('key') function. In **main.js**, when I call it.

```
{login: "Hh", senha: "Hu", imei: Promise, tipo: Promise, modelo: Promise, …}
imei:
Promise {_40: 0, _65: 1, _55: **"57d7bc714b269533"**, _72: null}
login: "Hh"
mobile_key:
Promise {_40: 0, _65: 1, _55: **null**, _72: null}
mobile_push:
Promise {_40: 0, _65: 1, _55: **"1"**, _72: null}
modelo:
Promise {_40: 0, _65: 1, _55: **"ASUS_Z00AD"**, _72: null}
senha: "Hu"
tipo:
Promise {_40: 0, _65: 1, _55: **"1"**, _72: null}
versao:
Promise {_40: 0, _65: 1, _55: **"1.0"**, _72: null}
__proto__: Object
```

PS.: some items up there is not a return from getItem().

Why does not it just return the single value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `storageGet` returns a promise, you need to also use await anywhere you use it:

```
const value = await storageGet(key);
```

Comment: using `await` only produces the following error `TypeError: bundle.added is undefined[Learn More]`

Comment: @Yokhen that sounds like an error that has nothing to do with using await.

Comment: Yeah I think it has to do with AsyncStorage

Answer (score 6):

AsyncStorage saves data only as strings. You just need to use JSON.stringify() when saving and JSON.parse() when retrieving.

```
AsyncStorage.getItem('key')
.then((value) => {
  const data = JSON.parse(value);
  console.log('name is ', data.name);
});
```